# Does the order of operands matter for an overloaded == operator in C#

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, operator-overloading

I am using a 3rd party tool (Unity3d), where one of the fundamental base classes overloads the == operator (*UnityEngine.Object*).

The overloaded operator's signature is:

```
public static bool operator == (UnityEngine.Object x, UnityEngine.Object y)
```

Does the order in which the comparison is made have any effect on whether this overloaded operator is used ?

To illustrate, should both of these use the overloaded operator and return the same result ?

```
// initialize with some value
UnityEngine.Object a = .... 

Debug.Log(a == null);
Debug.Log(null == a);
```

The reason i'm asking is because i'd like to (sometimes) avoid this overloaded behaviour (use the default == operator), and was wondering whether flipping the order would assist in that ?

(There could be another option - casting the operands to System.object, but I am not 100% sure that works).

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's possible that the two calls wouldn't be the same, if the operator had been overloaded badly. Either there could be one overload, and it could be written in a way which compares the operands asymmetrically, or the two statements could call different overloads.

But assuming it's been overloaded *properly*, that should be absolutely fine. That's if you *want* to call the overloaded operator, of course. In situations where you don't, I'd make that clear using [`ReferenceEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals).

I would personally recommend the `if (a == null)` approach, as I find it easier to read (and I believe many others do too). The "yoda" style of `if (null == a)` is sometimes used by C programmers who fear typos, where `if (a = null)` would be an assignment and a valid statement... albeit with a warning in decent C compilers.

Here's an example of a *badly* implemented set of overloads, where the operand order matters, because `null` is convertible to both `string` and `Test`:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    public static bool operator ==(Test t, string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test == string");
        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Test t, string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test != string");
        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(string x, Test t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("string == Test");
        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(string x, Test t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("string != Test");
        return false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t = null;
        Console.WriteLine(t == null);
        Console.WriteLine(null == t);
    }
}
```

Now that the question has been updated, we can tell that's not the case... but the implementation could still be poor. For example, it *could* be written as:

```
public static bool operator == (UnityEngine.Object x, UnityEngine.Object y)
{
    // Awful implementation - do not use!
    return x.Equals(y);
}
```

In that case, it will fail with a `NullReferenceException` when `x` is null, but succeed if `x` is non-null but `y` is null (assuming `Equals` has been written properly).

Again though, I'd *expect* that the operator has been written properly, and that this isn't a problem.

Comment: How can the two statements result in two different overload resolutions?

Comment: @zmbq: I'm just testing that now... (The two operands could have different types, but currently that's giving an error on invocation.)

Comment: @zmbq: I've got it now - it can definitely be different, although it's horrible. Will add an example.

Comment: Well, this link implies the order of operands doesn't affect the overload resolution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691326%28v=vs.71%29.aspx . It doesn't say so explicitly, though.

Comment: That link does seem like a good fit, but it's a bit complex (references other sections) and it seems a bit outdated. I've also updated my question with some more details

Comment: @zmbq: I don't see that it implies that at all, particularly with "The overload resolution rules of Section 7.4.2 are applied to the set of candidate operators to select the best operator with respect to the argument list (x, y)," See my updated answer for an example of where it *can* affect it.

Comment: Indeed, very interesting.

Comment: @lysergic-acid: I've updated my answer with an example of the "other" way it could fail, now that you've shown the signature. But basically it *should* be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet good answer, but i'm still not sure what would be the best way to avoid the overloaded operator... zmbq suggests (in his answer) to use ReferenceEquals(). Is that favorable to casting to System.object ?

Comment: @lysergic-acid: Yes, I'd use `ReferenceEquals` rather than casting, generally. I hadn't spotted that part of your update - please take care to ask all of your question from the start in future, if possible. If a question evolves a lot, it's hard for answerers to keep up, causing a generally confused page.

Comment: Comprison with null is a very important example in context of Unity, by the way. While `(a == null)` can be true, `if (a) { Debug.Log("Gets printed"); }` gets printed, because comparison of UnityObjects to null is overriden to signify Unity's state of being destroyed, not the actual null reference.

Comment: @golergka: What's the type of `a` in that case? It would have to have an implicit conversion to `bool` for that code to compile...

Comment: @JonSkeet UnityEngine.Object

Comment: @golergka: So *is* there an implicit conversion to `bool`?

Comment: @JonSkeet there is. However, I can't reproduce this on my current version of Unity; while this behaviour was certainly true before, it looks like it has changed, and may be they fixed it, not completely sure about it yet.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE after updating the question:

If you want to avoid calling the overloaded function when comparing to null, use `ReferenceEquals`:

```
if(a.ReferenceEquals(null)) ...
```

OLDER ANSWER, RENDERED OBSOLETE AND ALSO WRONG BY @Jon Skeet...

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691326%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), overload resolution of binary operator with X and Y as arguments is done by first taking the union of all operators defined by X and by Y.

So `a==b` results in exactly the same overload resolution as `b==a`.

The link is from 2003, but I doubt Microsoft has changed something since, it would have broken *a lot* of older code.

Comment: Thanks. does my suggestion work as well ? e.g: casting to object: if ( (System.Object)obj == null)

Comment: Unity game engine doesn't use Microsoft code; it relies on an *old* version of Mono, so it can theoretically be different or broken there.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Although I witnessed this behaviour in prior versions of Unity, I couldn't reproduce it in a test I performed right after writing this answer. May be Unity changed the `==` operator behaviour, or behaviour of implicit conversion of `UnityEngine.Object` to `bool`; however, I would still advocate using the overridden `==` operator instead of trying to avoid it.

The way Unity in particular overrides `==` operator is very frustrating, but also fundamental for how you have to work with the engine. After the UnityObject gets destroyed, by calling `Destroy` (some time after the call) or `DestroyImmediate` (immediately after the call, as the name would suggest), **the comparison of this object to null returns true**, even though it's not a null reference.

It's completely unintuitive for C# programmers, and can create a lot of truly WTF moments before you figure this out. Take this, for example:

```
DestroyImmediately(someObject);
if (someObject)
{
    Debug.Log("This gets printed");
}
if (someObject != null)
{
    Debug.Log("This doesn't");
}
```

The reason I'm explaining that is because I perfectly understand your desire to avoid this strange overridden behaviour, especially if you had C# experience before working with Unity. However, as with a lot of other Unity-specific stuff, it might actually be better to just stick to the Unity convention instead of trying to implement everything in the C#-correct way.

Comment: I am actually well aware of this conversion and the quirkiness of a null reference vs. a null "wrapper object" that Unity uses. The issue I am actually trying to avoid in this case is accessing an object from a different thread. We have a singleton that checks if its instance is null (the instance is a MonoBehaviour). Accessing it from another thread throws an exception (can't check whether instance == null from a different thread). In this case I'm interested in the plain old reference check. BTW i was told this behaviour was changed in Unity 5.

Comment: @lysergic-acid I'm sorry for being captain obvious then — 90% of people asking questions on unity3d tag are beginners, and I got into a habit of over-explaining everything. But with my experience, it's unrealistic to do anything with `UnityEngine.Object` instances in different threads, so I only use them with abstract pieces of work that doesn't use any of Unity API at all. If you can use other threads to work with Unity's objects successfully, can you write more about it?

Comment: It's indeed pretty much impossible to do stuff on anything other than the scripting thread. In Unity 5, however, the == operator works on other threads (didn't try it yet though).